# Increment all values in mysql table

Tags: mysql, increment, auto-increment

Lets say I have

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| isbn        | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| title       | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| author      | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The primary key was isbn (which I have now removed and I have added id (i will make primary soon) before I can do this i need to make sure that all id's are unique (so I want to update all values to increment starting at 1;

I have tried the following but it isn't working any suggestions?

```
SET @bookid = 1; UPDATE books SET `id` = @bookid + 1;
```

Comment: I think it would just be easier to create a new auto-inc table and `INSERT ... SELECT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
ALTER TABLE books AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

or if you haven't already id column, also add it

```
ALTER TABLE books ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD INDEX (id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran 
ALTER TABLE books DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE books ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for something like that

```
   SET @bookid = 1; 
   UPDATE books SET `id` =`id`+ @bookid ;
```

your query wll always give id = 2